# Using multiple credit cards for a single payment in the UK (section 75 protection)

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-card, car, consumer-protection

How can someone buy a product which is over each of its credit card limits, but less than his total credit?

Suppose that I want to buy a car, which is £4500, and suppose that I have three credit cards from three banks with credit limits of £2000, £2000, and £1000 pounds.

Also, suppose that I do have the money to buy the car. Therefore, I don't want to pay interest, and that I will pay the entire bills in the first month for all my bank.

The whole purpose of buying the car in a single transaction is to be protected by Section 75 of the Consumer Credit Act, meaning that if something goes wrong, I have more protection.

The problem in most shops/websites, you need to pay it in a single transaction. You can't pay a portion of the price with a credit card and the rest with another. What kind of fees am I expected to pay for "merging" these cards for a single transaction?

I am mostly thinking of keeping the three cards and not merging them indefinitely. Instead, I only want to merge them for ONE transaction, and then still having three cards.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome new user.  I'm not sure if you're aware, it's totally normal when you are buying (say) a car, to tell the person "I'll put 2000 on this card, 1000 on this card and 1000 on this card...".  That's a normal thing to do at shops, with anything over a few 100 quid.  You can do that normally at a car dealer

Comment: While what Fattie says is true, in the U.K. the dealer will usually put a (relatively low) limit on how much of the car you can pay for with a credit card specifically. (Debit cards are fine). If you’re borrowing money to buy it they’d much rather you took their financing rather than them having to pay credit card fees. Last time I bought a car there was a £2k limit on credit card, but I’m not sure if that was a fixed amount or a proportion of the purchase price.

Comment: @vicky that's a good point. Is this limit to void the customers' sec 75 protection? For example, if there's such limit on credit card payment (e.g. 2k), and the car is 4.5k, would I be only protected under section 75 for the portion paid by the credit card? Or the whole price?

Comment: @Ali I don't think the reason for the limit is to void that protection, but it does have that effect. You would only be protected for the amount paid on the credit card.

Comment: Partial payment does **not** limit the s.75 protection. "to claim under Section 75 you don't have to have paid more than £100 or the full amount on your credit card – the card company is liable even if you made only part of the payment (a deposit, say) on your card." https://www.which.co.uk/consumer-rights/regulation/section-75-of-the-consumer-credit-act